# how to make re-sizable columns in datatables

Tags: datatables, laravel-5

explain how to make column re-sizable in datatabels in laravel 5.2, can anyone explain step by step

"sDom": "Rlfrtip",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columnDefs: [{targets: [0, 13], orderable: false},
```